# Disable overlay when clicking anywhere on page

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a tooltip that I show and hide on click.  I want to **hide** the tooltip when the user clicks **anywhere** on the page.  How can I accomplish this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/e0agpgt2/17/)

```
var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
var Overlay = ReactBootstrap.Overlay;
var Tooltip = ReactBootstrap.Tooltip;
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;

const Example = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { show: true };
  },

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  },

  render() {
    const tooltip = <Tooltip>Tooltip overload!</Tooltip>;

    const sharedProps = {
      show: this.state.show,
      container: this,
      target: () => this.refs.target.getDOMNode()
    };

    return (
      <div style={{ height: 100, paddingLeft: 150, position: 'relative' }}>
        <Button ref="target" onClick={this.toggle}>
          Click me!
        </Button>

        <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>

        <Overlay {...sharedProps} placement="left">
          { tooltip }
        </Overlay>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


React.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass two props to your Overlay component to achieve that, `rootClose={true}` and `onHide={() => this.setState({show: false})}`

It should look like this

```
<Overlay rootClose={true} onHide={() => this.setState({show: false})} {...sharedProps} placement="left">
          { tooltip }
        </Overlay>
```

[full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/e0agpgt2/25/)

Comment: You posted just a few seconds before I figured it out and posted my own answer :)